# Socket chat android localhost connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, localhost

I have done developing my code for android chat app using sockets.

But for test purpose i need localhost connection to test app before making a scalable server.

Is it possible with localhost to check the following:

1. Transfer of messages with multimedia also possible
2. All other things like typing status and all
3. How to start doing it probably some tutorial?

Am I correct:

```
client = new Socket("localhost", port no);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), getPort()));
```

And for constants what should be done server port min and max is that necessary to update it with what?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Please consider rephrasing the question.

Comment: ok done edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to test your app at home.

Instructions how to write a simple Server in Java: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

As you Host take your PC's Local IP Adress and the Port you specified inside your Java Server.

Comment: ok thanks but can i test transfer of images etc from one android dev to another using localhost

Comment: Of course but you still need to implement it yourself on server side.

Comment: means i have coded it in android studio but i think you are telling me about stuff like using sqlite db to store messages containing images as  im doing it for simple text